# creating a polymorphic equals expression

Tags: java, polymorphism, equals

my question concerns altering an expression in java to make it polymorphic. The class is called csHash and is used to create hash-tables from a given datatype DT, and a given keytype KT. now, in several methods within the class (delete, search, insert, etc.) the method uses an equals function that, in the non-polymorphic version, simply uses String ( as the key in the non-polymorphic version is of the type String). what i was thinking is to create an equals method written as something along the lines of the following code. my question is... is it a valid means of testing equality?

```
public boolean equals(Object x) {
    String i;
    i = new String[1];     
    String y;
    y = new String[1];
    i == i + this;              // use the + operator to add 'this' object
    y == y + (findkey(other))x; // do the same for other object. findkey methods returns KT for a given object, i use this return to typecast the Object x.
    int j = i.compareTo(y);     // use built in String compare method

    if(j = 0) {return true;}    // use if else to determine if they are equal
    else {return false;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading the spec:

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.
>
> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null
>   object references:
>
> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x)
>   should return true. It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values
>   x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x)
>   returns true. It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x,
>   y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true,
>   then x.equals(z) should return true. It is consistent: for any
>   non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y)
>   consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no
>   information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified. For
>   any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.
>   The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).
>
> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.

In other words, as long as given three objects x, y, and z the following will hold:

```
x.equals(y) implies y.equals(x)
!x.equals(y) implies !y.equals(x)
x == y implies x.equals(y)
x.equals(y) && y.equals(z) implies x.equals(z)
```

If your equals method follows this contract, then it is a valid Java Object.equals implementation.  You can create lots and lots of unit tests for this quite easily to ensure all corner cases are covered.

Note that you will also have to override hashCode with the related behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your `equals` method is problematic as it doesn't compare the two hash tables with all items in the buckets. Also it doesn't exclude some cases. An example override of `equals` method in your `CSHash` class looks like the following to satisfy the general guideline of `equals` method:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof CSHash))
            return false;
        CSHash other = (CSHash) o;
        return this.entrySet().equals(other.entrySet());
    }
```

Here it assumes that you have defined `entrySet()` method in your `CSHash` class to return the  set of your hash table. You can define your own `entrySet()` method similar to the one in Java's HashMap class.

Comment: well the purpose of equals here isnt to compare two hash tables, but rather two different objects of the same class, that is two different students by comparing the key of that class ( names) or comparing two objects of the class cars by comparing their key ( mpg ). also this is a homemade hash class, it doesnt utilize the built in java one.

Comment: The equal method is a class member functions in your CSHash class, right? If so, then you need to use equal method to compare two objects of CSHash. Since a hash table consists of both key and value, so you need to compare an entrySet which is composed of both key and value. You don't need to use Java's built-in entrySet(), but you create your own entrySet() method for CSHash class. If you only need to compare keys, then you can simply override the equal method for the Key part only.